# Not allowed to set vflex and height at the same time except vflex="min" in ZK 8

Tags: java, zk

I am trying to change my zk version 7.0.8 to 8.0.1.1 .

Now I am getting this error `Not allowed to set vflex and height at the same time except vflex="min"`. Even I have changed all the zul file as per the above statement.

I already clean all the `vflex` and removed from all zul files but Zk-8 giving this error again and again.

```
    org.zkoss.zk.ui.UiException: Not allowed to set vflex and height at the same time except vflex="min"
at org.zkoss.zk.ui.HtmlBasedComponent.setHeight(HtmlBasedComponent.java:161)
at org.zkoss.zk.ui.HtmlBasedComponent$2.setValue(HtmlBasedComponent.java:668)
at org.zkoss.zk.ui.HtmlBasedComponent$2.setValue(HtmlBasedComponent.java:666)
at org.zkoss.zk.ui.metainfo.Property.assign0(Property.java:203)
at org.zkoss.zk.ui.metainfo.Property.assign(Property.java:171)
at org.zkoss.zk.ui.metainfo.ComponentInfo.applyProperties(ComponentInfo.java:732)
at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.AbstractUiFactory.newComponent(AbstractUiFactory.java:136)
at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild0(UiEngineImpl.java:908)
at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild(UiEngineImpl.java:877)
at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate0(UiEngineImpl.java:748)
at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate(UiEngineImpl.java:709)
at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild0(UiEngineImpl.java:923)
at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild(UiEngineImpl.java:877)
at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate0(UiEngineImpl.java:748)
at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate(UiEngineImpl.java:709)
at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild0(UiEngineImpl.java:923)
at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild(UiEngineImpl.java:877)
at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate0(UiEngineImpl.java:748)
at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate(UiEngineImpl.java:709)
at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild0(UiEngineImpl.java:923)
at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild(UiEngineImpl.java:877)
at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate0(UiEngineImpl.java:748)
at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate(UiEngineImpl.java:709)
at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild0(UiEngineImpl.java:923)
at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild(UiEngineImpl.java:877)
at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate0(UiEngineImpl.java:748)
at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild(UiEngineImpl.java:822)
at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate0(UiEngineImpl.java:771)
at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate(UiEngineImpl.java:709)
at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execNewPage0(UiEngineImpl.java:452)
at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execNewPage(UiEngineImpl.java:358)
at org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.DHtmlLayoutServlet.process(DHtmlLayoutServlet.java:217)
at org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.DHtmlLayoutServlet.doGet(DHtmlLayoutServlet.java:136)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:149)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.__invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.__invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2517)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2506)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Can you anyone help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Just put your component with vflex="min"
If that is not the idea, then show us what is your component in order to give you a better answer

Answer (score 1):

If its a maven project- Try to clean maven, update maven and then maven install. Some code in target. I guess so.

Answer (score 1):

This error is typical when you have a parent component with a  `vflex="[value]"` attribute and not precisely the `min` value (ie `vflex="1"`), then inside there is one or more components  defining a height, yo must look for it in all the nested  `*.zul's` if you are using `Composition` for example:

```
<vlayout vflex="1">
  ...
  <label  value="Error no height must be defined" heigh="200px"/> 
  ...
</vlayout>
```

Comment: And the 1million$ question. WHY this happenes on 8 version and not in zk 7 ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's the Tomcat's cache. Go in your Tomcat home and remove `work` and `temp` folder. After that run it again

Comment: Yes. I checked it before but issue is same. I don't understand why zk not providing proper error message. There is no specific file line or file name not there.